# Showing that $\mathbb P(A_n)\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow \int_{A_n}XdP\rightarrow 0$

Tags: probability-theory

> If $X$ is an integrable random variable and $\mathbb P(A_n)\rightarrow
>  0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $\int_{A_n}XdP\rightarrow 0$ as
> $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**My thoughts:**

As a result of the SLLN, we have that if $\mathbb P(A_n)\rightarrow 0$ then $\mathbb 1_{A_n}\rightarrow 0$ almost surely. I thought it would be useful to rewrite $\int_{A_n}XdP$ as

$$\int_{A_n}XdP=\int_\Omega X\mathbb 1_{A_n}dP$$

but it's not clear to me that $\mathbb 1_{A_n}\rightarrow 0$ would necessarily imply that $\int_\Omega X\mathbb 1_{A_n}dP\rightarrow 0$ since $X$ is not necessarily bounded. If it were bounded then $|X|\leq c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ and so

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{A_n} X dP
&\leq c\int_{A_n} dP\\\\
&=c\cdot\mathbb P(A_n)\\\\
&\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}$$

How can I proceed in the case where $X$ is not necessarily bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that $1_{A_n}$ converges to $0$ almost surely is false. For example, consider $\Omega=(0,1]$ with the Borel sigma algebra and the Lebesgue measure on it. (which is a probability measure). Then define $A_1=(0,\frac{1}{2}], A_2=(\frac{1}{2},1], A_3=(0,\frac{1}{4}], A_4=(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}], A_5=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}], A_6=(\frac{3}{4},1], A_7=(0,\frac{1}{8}]$ and so on. The sequence of probabilities really tends to zero, however the sequence of indicators doesn't converge to zero at **any** point.

What we do know is that $X1_{A_n}$ converges to $0$ in probability. Indeed, for every $\epsilon>0$ we have $\{|X1_{A_n}|>\epsilon\}\subseteq A_n$ and hence $\mathbb{P}(|X1_{A_n}|>\epsilon)\leq\mathbb{P}(A_n)\to 0$. Also, we have $|X1_{A_n}|\leq |X|$, and the random variable $X$ is integrable. Hence the required result follows from the dominated convergence theorem. (it works with convergence in measure, you don't need almost sure convergence)

Comment: This is probably a really obvious question but could you explain what the set $\{|X1_{A_n}|>\epsilon\}$ represents in words and why it's a subset of $A_n$? I'm still new to probability theory. I know $1_{A_n}$ takes on the value $1$ if $\omega\in A_n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: @Remy This is a short way to write the set $\{\omega\in\Omega: |X(\omega)1_{A_n}(\omega)|>\epsilon\}$. This set is contained in $A_n$ because if at a point $\omega$ we have $|X(\omega)1_{A_n}(\omega)|>\epsilon$ then in particular $1_{A_n}(\omega)\ne 0$, and hence $\omega\in A_n$.

Comment: That make sense, thanks! And the result follows from the dominant convergence theorem since the theorem states that if $|X1_{A_n}|\leq |X|$ then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb E(X 1_{A_n})=\mathbb E(X1_A)$. And since $X1_{A_n}$ converges to $0$ in probability (and since $A_n\uparrow A$) then $\mathbb E(X1_A)=0$ and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{A_n} XdP=0$?

Comment: @Remy The version of the dominated convergence theorem I am using states that if $Y_n\to Y$ in probability and there is an integrable random variable $Z$ such that $|Y_n|\leq Z$ for all $n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$. So in our case $Y_n=X1_{A_n}$, $Y=0$ and $Z=|X|$.